# Why is the following function call not thread-safe?

Tags: c, multithreading

I'm using Sun RPC to implement a simple pseudo-distributed storage system. I have three instances of the same server, and one client on the same machine.

Server RPC implementation goes something like this:

```
char **
fileread64k_1_svc(char *filename, long offset,  struct svc_req *rqstp)
{

    static char * readResult;
    //chunkName is a function of (fileName, offset)

    FILE *chunkFile = fopen(chunkName, "r");
    readResult = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (CHUNKSIZE + 2));
    fread(readResult, 1, CHUNKSIZE, chunkFile);
    readResult[CHUNKSIZE] = '\0';
    fclose(chunkFile);

    return &readResult;
}
```

I give my client a list of files to read, and the client creates 3 threads (one for each instance of the server) and the threads distribute the files among them, and call the read RPC like this:

```
while all files are not read:
    //pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    char **out = fileread64k_1(fileName, offset, servers[id]);
    //char *outData = *out;
    //pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
```

But the data in `out` is replaced by another thread before I have a chance to process it. If I enable the commented lines (the mutex and the `outData` variable), I get the data in `outData` and I seem to be able to safely use it.

Can anyone explain why this happens and if there is a better workaround?

Comment: Why are you returning the address of `readResult`?  Just returning `readResult` might solve your problem.   Also,  declaring `readResult` as `static` inside your function may not be what you want.

Comment: Oh, this is the first time I'm writing RPC code, and `static` part was generated by `rpcgen`, so I just assumed you had to do that. I'll try changing it. Thanks!

Comment: You might consider editing the title and tags of this post to remove mention of Sun RPC or rpc in general.  The issue isn't really related to RPCs but to C and multithreading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because "readResult" is declared static.  That means that all invocations of the method use the same space in memory for that variable, including concurrent invocations in different threads.

The problem should be taken care of if you just don't declare readResult as static -- but in that case, you won't be able to return its address, you should return the value of readResult itself.

Incidentally, which code has the responsibility of free()ing the allocated memory?

Comment: Eek, I never free that memory! (I wrote this in an overnight marathon one day before the deadline), but I suppose I'd do it in the client threads, after processing the `outData` variable.